# How can i check if css class exists on page and add new one to the body

Tags: theming

something like:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  //if css.class exists on page{
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'my-class';
 //}
}
```

... All i want is to add class to other elements if there is custom views (module:views) on my landing-page

Comment: I am not sure what your set up is. I know Panels can make this a little difficult. If you are not using panels preprocess_node should have both your view and page vars. I am fairly certain but not 100%, I have been on Panels for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'new-class';
}
```

or

```
if ($('body.mydivclass').length > 0) {
  $('body').addClass('new-class');
}
```